# Improving a Monte Carlo code to find the volume of sphere in Higher dimension. (PYTHON)

Tags: python

Considering Gaussian shape  we can find the  volume of n dimensional volume of a sphere. My intention is to find the  volume using Monte Carlo method.

Using the gaussian integral I have found the formula

[image]

What I understand that the ratio of the points inside the n-dimensional sphere to the total number of points will then be roughly the same as the ratio of the volume of the ball to that of the cube. I mean the mass density would never change , whatever dimension I use.

Therefore  I assume I should follow the same technique what  I used to find the value of pi using Monte Carlo method.

I don't understand how to  follow the  code  which I evaluated to find the value of pi.

```
import random

TIMES_TO_REPEAT = 10**5
LENGTH = 10**5

def in_circle(x, y):
    return x**2 + y**2 < LENGTH**2

inside_count = 0
for _ in range(TIMES_TO_REPEAT):
    point = random.randint(0,LENGTH), random.randint(0,LENGTH)
    if in_circle(*point):
        inside_count += 1

pi = (inside_count / TIMES_TO_REPEAT) * 4

print(pi)
```

How can I apply the inequality condition in the code I have mentioned so the mass density would be same and I can find the value of volume in Higher dimension.?

Comment: "Can you help me building the code" is too broad a question for this site.  You need to try to do it yourself, and then, if necessary, ask a specific question about a specific problem you encounter.

Comment: I understand  that The same strategy I need to adapt and I have tried to   do it too, but i got error. I think if someone  can do it for 4th or 5th dimension, I can follow in the same way. I have evaluated the volume  in other way but  I'm new in Monte Carlo method.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

N = 10**5 # number of trials (ie, number of points to sample)
R = 10**5 # circle radius

def in_sphere(x, y, z):
    return x**2 + y**2 + z**2 < R**2

c = 0
for _ in range(N):
    p = random.randint(0,R), random.randint(0,R), random.randint(0,R)
    if in_sphere(*p):
        c += 1

pi = 6 * c / N
print(pi)
```

Comment: You need to work out the formula for higher dimensions. This is not a Python question though.

Comment: Dear Ancora thanks for  answering.  I would like to find volume in higher dimension instead of pi using the Monte Carlo  method.

Comment: As I said, this is NOT a Python but a math question.

Comment: Are you really asking this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/894378/volume-of-a-cube-and-a-ball-in-n-dimensions

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea: if a circle (radius *R*) is inscribed inside a square (then, its edge must be *2R*), then the ratio (the area of circle over the area of square) will be *π/4*. So, if you pick *N* points at random inside the square, approximately *N * π/4* of those points should fall inside the circle.

hope the annotated/revised code help you understand the MC logic

```
import random

N = 10**5 # number of trials (ie, number of points to sample)
R = 10**5 # circle radius

# whether p(x,y) is inside a circle
def in_circle(x, y):
    return x**2 + y**2 < R**2

# use integer ops as much as possible for speed
c = 0
for i in range(N):
    x, y = random.randint(0,R), random.randint(0,R)
    if in_circle(x, y):
        c += 1

pi = 4 * c / N
print(pi) # pi-> 3.14
```

Comment: To expand to higher dimensions, just change the in_cirlce. For example, for 3d, it will be in_sphere(x,y,z)

Comment: Could you change this code for the forth dimension and find the volume? I understood your code since I have mentioned it in my question too?